# Print lines indexed by a second file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files:

1. File with strings (new line terminated)
2. File with integers (one per line)

I would like to print the lines from the first file indexed by the lines in the second file. My current solution is to do this

```
while read index
do
    sed -n ${index}p $file1
done < $file2
```

It essentially reads the index file line by line and runs sed to print that specific line. The problem is that it is slow for large index files (thousands and ten thousands of lines).

Is it possible to do this faster? I suspect awk can be useful here.

I search SO to my best but could only find people trying to print line ranges instead of indexing by a second file.

UPDATE

The index is generally not shuffled. It is expected for the lines to appear in the order defined by indices in the index file.

EXAMPLE

File 1:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

File 2:

```
3
2
```

The expected output is:

```
this is line 3
this is line 2
```

Comment: Doesn't the `paste` command do what you want?

Comment: @barmar I think you misunderstood my use of the word ``indexed''. I meant to select the lines using the line numbers from the file with indices only (integers). This is not about pasting two files together.

Comment: Post some small but representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then

```
awk 'NR == FNR { selected[$1] = 1; next } selected[FNR]' indexfile datafile
```

should work, under the assumption that the index is sorted in ascending order or you want lines to be printed in their order in the data file regardless of the way the index is ordered. This works as follows:

```
NR == FNR {         # while processing the first file
  selected[$1] = 1  # remember if an index was seen
  next              # and do nothing else
}
selected[FNR]       # after that, select (print) the selected lines.
```

If the index is not sorted and the lines should be printed in the order in which they appear in the index:

```
NR == FNR {               # processing the index:
  ++counter
  idx[$0] = counter       # remember that and at which position you saw
  next                    # the index
}
FNR in idx {              # when processing the data file: 
  lines[idx[FNR]] = $0    # remember selected lines by the position of
}                         # the index
END {                     # and at the end: print them in that order.
  for(i = 1; i <= counter; ++i) {
    print lines[i]
  }
}
```

This can be inlined as well (with semicolons after `++counter` and `index[FNR] = counter`, but I'd probably put it in a file, say `foo.awk`, and run `awk -f foo.awk indexfile datafile`. With an index file

```
1
4
3
```

and a data file

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

this will print

```
line1
line4
line3
```

The remaining caveat is that this assumes that the entries in the index are unique. If that, too, is a problem, you'll have to remember a list of index positions, split it while scanning the data file and remember the lines for each position. That is:

```
NR == FNR {               
  ++counter
  idx[$0] = idx[$0] " " counter  # remember a list here
  next
}
FNR in idx {              
  split(idx[FNR], pos)    # split that list
  for(p in pos) {
    lines[pos[p]] = $0    # and remember the line for
                          # all positions in them.
  }
}
END {
  for(i = 1; i <= counter; ++i) {
    print lines[i]
  }
}
```

This, finally, is the functional equivalent of the code in the question. How complicated you have to go for your use case is something you'll have to decide.

Answer (score 3):

This awk script does what you want:

```
$ cat lines
1
3
5
$ cat strings 
string 1
string 2
string 3
string 4
string 5
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}FNR in a' lines strings 
string 1
string 3
string 5
```

The first block only runs for the first file, where the line number for the current file `FNR` is equal to the total line number `NR`. It sets a key in the array `a` for each line number that should be printed. `next` skips the rest of the instructions. For the file containing the strings, if the line number is in the array, the default action is performed (so the line is printed).

Answer (score 2):

Use `nl` to number the lines in your strings file, then use `join` to merge the two:

```
~ $ cat index
1
3
5

~ $ cat strings
a
b
c
d
e

~ $ join index <(nl strings)
1 a
3 c
5 e
```

---

If you want the inverse (show lines that *NOT* in your index):

```
$ join -v 2 index <(nl strings)
2 b
4 d
```

---

Mind also the comment by @glennjackman: if your files are not lexically sorted, then you need to sort them before passing in:

```
$ join <(sort index) <(nl strings | sort -b)
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. `join` may warn that the files aren't sorted -- it requires lexical sorting, not numeric. An enhancement: `join <(sort index) <(nl string | sort -b)`

Comment: Interesting use of the ``join'' utility! Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete the answers that use awk, here's a solution in Python that you can use from your bash script:

```
cat << EOF | python
lines = []
with open("$file2") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(int(line))

i = 0
with open("$file1") as f:
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        if i in lines:
            print line,
EOF
```

The only advantage here is that Python is way more easy to understand than awk :).

Comment: `Python is way more easy to understand than awk` - that is hilarious. I'm tempted to upvote your answer just for that :-).